# AngularJS:How do I display the rows in three lines using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[image: Screenshot 1]

How do I display the rows in three lines using ng-repeat

```
 $scope.ui.products = [
      {id : "multiLine", name : "Line"},
      {id : "multiBar", name : "Bar"},
      {id : "pie", name : "Pie"}
    ];
  <span ng-repeat="p in products track by p.id">
        {{ p.name }}

      </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a `<br>`

```
 $scope.ui.products = [
      {id : "multiLine", name : "Line"},
      {id : "multiBar", name : "Bar"},
      {id : "pie", name : "Pie"}
    ];
  <div ng-repeat="p in products track by p.id">
       <span> {{ p.name }} </span> <br>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's not working.Need to display data in three different div

Answer (score 0):

**controller.js**

```
$scope.ui.products = [
      {id : "multiLine", name : "Line"},
      {id : "multiBar", name : "Bar"},
      {id : "pie", name : "Pie"}
    ];
```

**index.html**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="product in products track by product.id>
        {{ product.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need to display the data in three different div.

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to do it in an ng-repeat and not bind every object to a different div?

Update >>>>

Try this:

```
$scope.ui.products = [
  {id : "multiLine", name : "Line"},
  {id : "multiBar", name : "Bar"},
  {id : "pie", name : "Pie"}
];

<div ng-repeat="p in products track by p.id">
   {{ p.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please see the image I have just attached.I need to display the data in three divs.But all the data are appearing repeatedly in three divs.

Comment: Check this out. jsfiddle.net/trxzr/1

Comment: It doesnt work.Need to display the data in three different divs.